# Passing request as is from a service to another

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, multer

I am having the following scenario:

1. i have a Loopback service (Core) that has a remote method **POST /Core/{id}/upload** (accessible to public)

> Core.remoteMethod('upload', {
>           accepts: [
>               {
>                   arg: 'id',
>                   type: 'string',
>                   description: 'The Entity instance ID.',
>                   required: true,
>                   http: {source: 'path'}
>               },
>               {
>                   arg: 'req',
>                   type: 'object',
>                   required: true,
>                   description: 'The request object.',
>                   http: {source: 'req'}
>               }
>           ],
>           returns: {
>               arg: 'output',
>               type: '$new_EntityPostResponseProps',
>               root: true,
>               description: 'Returns the entity instances that was updated.'
>           },
>           description: 'Upload a resource to the specified resource.',
>           documented: true,
>           http: {
>               verb: 'patch',
>               path: '/:id/upload'
>           }
>       });

2. i have another Loopback service (Entities) that has a remote method
   **POST /Entities/{id}/upload** (not accessible to public)

> Entities.remoteMethod('upload', {
>           accepts: [
>               {
>                   arg: 'id',
>                   type: 'string',
>                   description: 'The Entity instance ID.',
>                   required: true,
>                   http: {source: 'path'}
>               },
>               {
>                   arg: 'user',
>                   type: 'string',
>                   required: true,
>                   description: 'The User instance ID.',
>                   http: {source: 'query'}
>               },
>               {
>                   arg: 'files',
>                   type: 'string',
>                   required: true,
>                   description: 'The request.',
>                   http: {source: 'form'}
>               }
>           ],
>           returns: {
>               arg: 'output',
>               type: 'Entities',
>               root: true,
>               description: 'Returns the entity instance that was updated.'
>           },
>           description: 'Update the updated Entity instance.',
>           documented: true,
>           http: {
>               verb: 'patch',
>               path: '/:id/upload'
>           }
>       });

3. i use *loopback-connector-swagger* to connect the two services
4. i use *multer* to handle multipart/form-data requests

I have the following problem:

1. i upload a file using the **POST /Core/{id}/upload** endpoint
2. the sent file is received on the Core service in the following format:

> { fieldname: 'file', originalname: 'quickstart.mp4', encoding: '7bit',
>   mimetype: 'video/mp4', buffer: <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 42 6c 6f
>   62 20 53 44 4b 20 4e 49 43 55 20 56 52 45 41 20 41 73 74 61...>,
>   size: 29 }

3. I then do a JSON.stringify(file) and send as a *string* field through swagger to the Entities service, on the Entities service i do a JSON.parse on the parameter
4. if the file has 100mb the JSON.stringify crashes the server
5. there is also a considerate delay between Core and Entities until the file is passed completely

**How can i pass the request received by Core, unaltered and unchanged through swagger to the Entities service?** (Core should be just a pass-through service, i should not be doing JSON.stringify on file data, i just want to pass it along to the Entities service)

If i can't send the request unaltered i figured that i may send the file data buffer directly to the Entities service, but i did not get it to work, it shows as undefined.

Suggestions and samples are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!